# Installing GLPK/CBC

Tags: windows, python-3.6, solver, pyomo, glpk

I am new to Pyomo and would love to use it and call GLPK or CBC. However, I am struggling to get any of them working, perhaps I am not able to install and call them correctly. I am using windows and would appreciate any input.

Here is an error message I am receiving:

> "Could not locate the 'glpsol' executable, which is required for solver 'glpk'"

I am using python 3.6.

Comment: I cannot use conda-forge too. I am using the company computer and I can only download the solvers locally.

Comment: I would download the glpsol.exe executable and then add the directory that you place it in on the system PATH. I'm on bad wifi right now, but you ought to be able to look up how to add a folder to the PATH.

Comment: Thanks! They are now working.